# ‘The application "AppDownloadLauncher" is not open anymore’ when attempting to open Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore

I have just downloaded Xcode off the App Store and now when I try to open it I get this error:

> The application "AppDownloadLauncher" is not open anymore.

[image: Error message screenshot]

What does this mean and how do I open Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

The process AppDownloadLauncher is used to launch apps from the Mac App Store. The error is shown when a problem occurred communicating with this process.

Use Activity Monitor to force quit AppDownloadLauncher, then try relaunching Xcode.
If this doesn't help, log out and back in.